# Saltar error en script de R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tengo el siguiente código (lo dejo al final) para hacer diversos cálculos de regresión logística en R. El código me hace todos los cálculos que necesito. Pero cuando acaba con el código que presento, me lanza un mensaje de error:

```
Error in approx(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Esto ocurre por un asunto intrínseco de la regresión logística: me dice que en algunas ocasiones no ha podido realizar el cálculo y ha introducido un `NA`.

Como he dicho, el código sí hace todos lo que yo necesito (incluso esos `NA` me son útiles). Pero, al lanzarme este error/aviso, el script se para y no continua con la línea siguiente. En realidad es una línea para exportar el resultado en un archivo csv.

Quiero saber cómo evitar que el script se pare y continúe con la exportación de los resultados.

Gracias.

Código:

```
for(x in enfermedades){
  for(y in comunidades){
    df2 <- filter(df, df$ENFERMEDAD == "HEALTHY" | df$ENFERMEDAD == x)
    nc1 <- which(variables == x)
    nc2 <- which(variables == y)
    fit <- glm(df2[ , nc1] ~ df2[ , nc2], data = df2, family = binomial)
    fit <- fit %>% tidy(conf.int = TRUE, exp = TRUE)
    enfermedad <- x
    comunidad <- y
    or <- round(fit$estimate[2], 3)
    or_inf <- round(fit$conf.low[2], 3)
    or_sup <- round(fit$conf.high[2], 3)
    p_valor <- round(fit$p.value[2], 3)
    probabilidad <- round((or / (or + 1)) * 100, 1)
    df2 <- data.frame(enfermedad, comunidad, or, or_inf, or_sup, p_valor, probabilidad)
    logistica <- rbind(logistica, df2)
  }
}

write_csv2(logistica, "logistica_resultados.csv")
```

Comment: Parece que tienes un grupo con observaciones insuficientes para el glm, debes incluir una prueba como `if(length(nc1)>=2){ .. }else{next}`. Ahora, 2 observaciones para un glm binomial es muy poco, te aconsejo que evalúes bien la cantidad de observaciones mínimas por grupo para entrenar el glm

Comment: Hola, @aldo_tapia Sí, soy consciente de ello. No hay problema con eso. De hecho, que introduzca esos NA me sirve para detectar esas comparaciones. Pero lo que quiero es que el script no pare cuando me muestra el aviso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo. Os dejo el código debajo. Gracias.

```
logistica_calc <- function(x, y){
    tryCatch(
    {
    enfermedades <- x
    comunidades <- y

    for(x in enfermedades){
      for(y in comunidades){
        df2 <- filter(df, df$ENFERMEDAD == "HEALTHY" | df$ENFERMEDAD == x)
        nc1 <- which(variables == x)
        nc2 <- which(variables == y)
        fit <- glm(df2[ , nc1] ~ df2[ , nc2], data = df2, family = binomial)
        fit <- fit %>% tidy(conf.int = TRUE, exp = TRUE)
        enfermedad <- x
        comunidad <- y
        or <- round(fit$estimate[2], 3)
        or_inf <- round(fit$conf.low[2], 3)
        or_sup <- round(fit$conf.high[2], 3)
        p_valor <- round(fit$p.value[2], 3)
        probabilidad <- round((or / (or + 1)) * 100, 1)
        df2 <- data.frame(enfermedad, comunidad, or, or_inf, or_sup, p_valor, probabilidad)
        logistica <- rbind(logistica, df2)
      }
    }
    
    write_csv2(logistica, "logistica_resultados.csv")
    write_sav(df, "CLOM5_df_v1_mod.sav")
    },
    
    error = function(e){
        write_csv2(logistica, "logistica_resultados.csv")
        write_sav(df, "CLOM5_df_v1_mod.sav")
    }
    )
}

logistica_calc(enfermedades, comunidades)
```